# CLSID_InternetExplorerMedium and SDK 6.1

Tags: internet-explorer, com, automation

I am trying to use CLSID_InternetExplorerMedium with Platform SDK 6.1.

Although this CLSID is not defined in SDK 6.1, I have got ExDisp.h from SDK 7.1.

The compilation is successful but linking fails 'undefined symbol'

Which LIB file / other file (TLB) should I borrow from SDK 7.1 to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Headers and Libraries for Windows Internet Explorer 9](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22934) and link with `uuid.lib` from there. Or, just use `__uuidof(InternetExplorerMedium)` instead of `CLSID_InternetExplorerMedium` and you won't need additional libraries.